# Java compilation confusion: why does this code compile?

Tags: java, javac

I am not sure why this code (gives stackoverflow at runtime) compiles:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StackOverflow {
   StackOverflow overflow = new StackOverflow();

   public void myCall() {
       overflow.myPrint();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       StackOverflow newStackOverflow = new StackOverflow();
       newStackOverflow.myCall();
   }

   public void myPrint() {
       System.out.println("I am confused!");
   }
}
```

The reason why I am confused is coz, within the class definition, I am trying to create an object of the class I am trying to define. Shouldn't this be a compile time error?

Comment: Generally, you want to pick up subtle bugs which the developer is unlikely to pickup just by read/running the code.  In this case, the error will be apparent as soon as you attempt to run it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a compile-time error because the compiler can't tell if it's going to be infinitely generated at compile-time.

You and I can look at that and see it for sure, but the compiler only cares that the declarations are correct.  There's nothing *syntactically* illegal about this declaration, which is why the compiler will just let it go.

It's related to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), in that a program can't report if it will successfully halt.

Comment: I don't know about the compiler but surely some checker like Findbugs would be able to warn about the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It could be argued, I suppose, that the compiler should catch this recursive version of an infinite loop, but there's nothing in the language definition that makes it illegal for an object to construct another instance of itself when being instantiated.

It certainly is something I'd expect code analysis tools like [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) to complain about.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not a problem with Java. It's pretty fast and loose about dynamic declarations and not needing to have things declared before they're used. It figures it all later, and it makes the language a bit easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you a stack overflow exception because every time you create a StackOverflow, the line

```
StackOverflow overflow = new StackOverflow();
```

Creates another StackOverflow, which creates another one, and so on and so on until the stack maxes out and throws an exception.

Comment: I think OP knows why the stack is overflowing and is asking why such a construct is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

No. Java does nothing to detect infinite loops or infinite recursions at compile time.
You can compile code like yours or the method below just fine, it will blow up at runtime.

```
 private int recurseForever(){
     return recurseForever();
 }
```

In your case, the constructor creates a new instance of the class and thus calls another constructor and so on.

As for why it does not do so: Because it is impossible to do it for all cases (halting problem), and throwing resources at a partial solution (that works only sometimes, but makes compilation slower always and for everyone, possibly also introducing bugs because the compiler is more complicated now) was apparently not deemed a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's really not possible for a compiler to catch every possible way you could do this, there's no requirement that the compiler catch it. In general, unlimited recursion is only detectable at run time. (And even then, all you can detect is that it exceed the permitted limits.)

Answer (score 0):

> The reason why I am confused is coz, within the class definition, I am trying to create an object of the class I am trying to define. Shouldn't this be a compile time error?

When the compiler sees this piece of code, you have already defined your class completely and compiler can create an object of this class without ambiguity. Hence this shows no compile time errors.

Answer (score 0):

No it should not give error, by writing following line `StackOverflow overflow = new StackOverflow();` you are actually creating an instance variable in a class. And this line `StackOverflow newStackOverflow = new StackOverflow();` is going to create your local variable.

if you update your code as follows, then also it will going to work.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StackOverflow {
   private static StackOverflow overflow = new StackOverflow();

   public void myCall() {
       overflow.myPrint();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       overflow.myCall();
   }

   public void myPrint() {
       System.out.println("I am confused!");
   }
}
```

Comment: That won't even compile. You can't directly reference an instance variable `overflow` from the static method `main`.